# Using ADO.Net, how do I get the database table name associated with a DataColumn?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Assume that I have a table t1 with a column c1. When I execute a 'select c1 from t1', I can get the metadata for the result using DataTable/DataRow/DataColumn using the code snippet below

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SqlDataAdapter adapter;
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            using (SqlConnection connection
                = new SqlConnection(@"Persist Security Info=False;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
            {

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                    @"SELECT c1 from t1 where 1 = 0;", connection);
                connection.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetName(0)); //Name of column
                foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(row["TableName"]);
                    foreach (DataColumn column in schemaTable.Columns)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}",
                            column.ColumnName, row[column]));

                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the value returned for BaseTableName is blank. Are there any other methods available to get the table 't1' associated with the column 'c1'?

Here is the output of the above code :

```
ColumnName = c1
ColumnOrdinal = 0
ColumnSize = 100
NumericPrecision = 255
NumericScale = 255
IsUnique = False
IsKey = 
BaseServerName = 
BaseCatalogName = 
BaseColumnName = c1
BaseSchemaName = 
BaseTableName = 
DataType = System.String
AllowDBNull = True
ProviderType = 3
IsAliased = 
IsExpression = 
IsIdentity = False
IsAutoIncrement = False
IsRowVersion = False
IsHidden = 
IsLong = False
IsReadOnly = False
ProviderSpecificDataType = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString
DataTypeName = char
XmlSchemaCollectionDatabase = 
XmlSchemaCollectionOwningSchema = 
XmlSchemaCollectionName = 
UdtAssemblyQualifiedName = 
NonVersionedProviderType = 3
IsColumnSet = False
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the table name using

schemaTable.TableName

Following links will provide you the information you are looking for:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.tablename(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.table(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The schemaTable.TableName property returns the string 'SchemaTable' and not the expected value 't1'.  This is the test code I used DataTable table = row.Table;
                    Console.WriteLine(table.TableName);

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to get all table/column info

```
Select * From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it here:

```
//Console.WriteLine(row["table_name"]);
```

Try changing it to:

```
Console.WriteLine(row["TableName"]);
```

Comment: It threw an exception System.ArgumentException when I did that. The exception read "Additional information: Column 'TableName' does not belong to table SchemaTable."

Comment: Is there something else that I need to do to get a "full" picture of the mapping ? Can you point me to the documentation where you found it should be "TableName" and not "table_name" ? Maybe that documentation has an answer to my question. And you must have a hawk's eye. You actually noticed the commented piece //Console.WriteLine(row["table_name"]); amongst all those lines of code.

Comment: @QFirstLast That's interesting. I found "TableName" by inspecting the `List` property in `schemaTable.Columns` in Visual Studio. Can you update your question with the sample out put for a Row? Does the table name show up under a different property?

Comment: I attached the output to the question. What I find interesting is that the t1.c1 is of type integer in the database while the output seems to suggest otherwise.